# Ionic Build on Mac for Android emulator throwing Kotlin Error

Tags: macos, android-studio, ionic-framework, kotlin

on my mac machine i have installed android studio and set up the android home, i am able to run the app in ios emulator, however when i am trying to run the same app in android emulator using the command:

```
ionic cordova build android
```

I am getting the following error:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download kotlin-reflect.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.1.3-2)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.1.3-2/kotlin-reflect-1.1.3-2.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.1.3-2/kotlin-reflect-1.1.3-2.jar'.
            > d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net
```

lot of Kotlin updates related error, in the Android studio in the configure menu i did update the Kotlin plugins and restarted the machine as well.

Any help on the same would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the Android SDK manager i had to uncheck Kotlin in the plugins :(